# MYSQL - get first record based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have the following employee_sequence table

```
| id | employee_id | sequence_id | is_completed |
|----|:-----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|
| 1  |      12     |      3      |       1      |
| 2  |      12     |      4      |       1      |
| 3  |      10     |      3      |       1      |
| 4  |      10     |      4      |       0      |
```

I am looking for how to get, in 1 query, the first row having is_completed = 0 for an employee.  If no such row for that employee, then take first row having is_completed = 1

Example for employee_id = 12 (there is no is_completed = 0, so first row having is_completed = 1)

```
| id | employee_id | sequence_id | is_completed |
|----|:-----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|
| 1  |      12     |      3      |       1      |
```

Example for employee_id = 10 (first row having is_completed = 0)

```
| id | employee_id | sequence_id | is_completed |
|----|:-----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|
| 4  |      10     |      4      |       0      |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`, if yu are running MySQL 8.0; assumuming that `id` can be used to order the records, you would phrase this as:

```
select *
from (
    select es.*, row_number() over(partition by employee_id order by is_completed, id) rn
    from employee_sequence es
) es
where rn = 1
```

In ealier version, an alternative is a correlated subquery with a row-limiting clause:

```
select *
from employee_sequence es
where es.id = (
    select es1.id
    from employee_sequence es1
    where es1.employee_id = es.employee_id
    order by es1.is_completed, es.id
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: A very valid point. Your answer prefers `is_completed = 1` over `is_completed = 0`. In other words, your `order by` clause is incorrect. Re-read the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this *per employee* (as your question suggests):

```
select es.*
from employee_sequence es
where es.employee_id = 12
order by is_completed, id
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79ab6279059a8ddaf6637da120a65099) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This query doesn't give any results

Comment: @user1841557 . . . The only way this query could not give results is if there is no row with `employee_id = 12`.

Comment: @user1841557 . . . That comment i  even more baffling.  Why are you saying this won't work?

Comment: I tried the query you suggested. It does not solve the problem, returns no result.  The post by GMB, below works best for me.

Comment: @user1841557 . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  This code works and it does exactly what you specify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222851/discussion-between-user1841557-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running something less than MySql 8 then:

```
select * from employee_sequence e1
where e1.id = (
  select e2.id
  from employee_sequence e2
  where e2.employee_id = e1.employee_id
  order by e2.is_completed, e2.sequence_id
  limit 1
);


| id  | employee_id | sequence_id | is_completed |
| --- | ----------- | ----------- | ------------ |
| 1   | 12          | 3           | 1            |
| 4   | 10          | 4           | 0            |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kJAQPTgLdeGPxcr9WUNaNm/1)